# What is wrong with this simple shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to Shell script. Just have a small question about some script I wrote.

```
pkgs="./cppcheck-1.48.tar.bz2 ./sshpass-1.04.tar.gz"
for pkg in $pkgs ; do
echo ${pkg} | grep -qE "bz2$"

if [ $? ] ; then
                echo "here1"
else
                echo "here2"            
fi

done
```

It always prints here1, i.e. if condition is always true. I am not able to pin point any reason for it till now. Please point me towards right direction.

I know I can use shell's switch command. Just want to know what is wrong with this. Shell is /bin/bash

[EDIT] - switch statement works flawlessly. For those who face this problem some other time

```
case ${pkg} in
     *bz2) echo "here1";;
     *) echo "here2";;
esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if [ $? ]` does not work as you might expect:

```
$ false ; if [ $? ] ; then echo "true" ; else echo "false" ; fi 
true
$ true ; if [ $? ] ; then echo "true" ; else echo "false" ; fi 
true
```

It's easy enough to fix by comparing against `0` explicitly:

```
$ false ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "true" ; else echo "false" ; fi 
false
$ true ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "true" ; else echo "false" ; fi 
true
```

So for your script:

```
pkgs="./cppcheck-1.48.tar.bz2 ./sshpass-1.04.tar.gz"
for pkg in $pkgs ; do
echo ${pkg} | grep -qE "bz2$"

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                echo "here1"
else
                echo "here2"            
fi

done

here1
here2
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash has both arithmetic and conditional expressions.

The answer sarnold gives is a way to force this to work using a conditional expression but if you want to use an arithmetic expression instead you can replace

```
[ $? ]
```

with

```
(( $? ))
```

If you search the bash man pages for these topics there is a lot more information on how these work.

edit: My mistake, conditional expressions are [[ ]].  (( )) gives the behaviour you were probably expecting though.

Comment: Thanks. I really liked your answer. Pointed me towards something I did not know.Upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo ${pkg} | grep -qE "bz2$"` by `echo ${pkg} | grep -q -E "bz2$"`
and it will work like a charm! 
[EDIT]
Oops.. also change the if () condition to 
`if [ $? -ne 1 ] ; then`